# Convert CSV to JSON tree structure (hierarchical) using amCharts?

Tags: python, json, csv, tree, amcharts4

I am using the force-directed tree from amCharts https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/ to visualize data from json file using the following (in place of the chart.data part of the code):

```
chart.dataSource.url = "test.json";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
chart.dataSource.parser.options.emptyAs = 0;
```

However, I want to convert a csv file into a hierarchy json file first. I have attempted this solution [Convert csv to JSON tree structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757965/convert-csv-to-json-tree-structure) but it did not work for the following csv file

```
condition, target, sub, dub
oxygen,tree,G1,T1
oxygen,tree,G2,T1
oxygen,tree,G2,T2
water,car,G3,T1
water,tree,GZ,T1
water,tree,GZ,T2
fire,car,GTD,T3
oxygen,bomb,GYYS,T1
```

It displays three separate trees instead.